# What is the correct use of "only"; "solo" or "sólo"?

Tags: acentuación, español-neutral

In Spanish, "sólo" means only. But I have read many texts with "sólo" (*with* accent) and many others with "solo" (*without* accent). Which version is correct in Neutral Spanish?

Comment: neutral Spanish? Never heard of that. Please look up questions in the RAE (rae.es) before asking them here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/solo-sin-tilde-193/), this has changed some time ago, and now **it is always correct and recommended to write "solo" without accent**. An accent is allowed if "solo" means "only" **and** there is a risk of ambiguity with the other meaning "alone":

- Ha montado solo la mesa

which can mean "he has built only the table" or "he has built the table alone". In this case, it is possible to write "sólo" if the meaning is "only", but it is also correct to leave it without accent.

Comment: To get rid of ambiguity, we can say *solamente* to mean *only*.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tiene sentido.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It makes sense.